# button does not function like a button, what errors exist in this Stripe-generated code?

Tags: stripe-payments

I simply don't know JS well enough to determine the issue. I'm sure it's glaring at me, in plain sight. I just need the button to function like a button. When I move the cursor over the button and click, neither do anything.

I've tried adding the type, as you can see.

```
    <!-- Load Stripe.js on your website. -->
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>

    <!-- Create a button that your customers click to complete their purchase. Customize the styling to suit your branding. -->
    <button
  style="background-color:#6772E5;color:#FFF;padding:8px 12px;border:0;border-radius:4px;font-size:1em"
  id="checkout-button-plan_555xxx555"
  role="link"
  type="button"
>
  Checkout
</button>

<div id="error-message"></div>

<script>
(function() {
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_555xxx555');

  var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-plan_G2Z8GjQU8ZihZw');
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
    // them to Checkout.
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [{plan: '555xxx555', quantity: 1}],

      // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
      // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
      // a successful payment.
      // Instead use one of the strategies described in
      // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
      successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//cozelosdata.com/success',
      cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//cozelosdata.com/canceled',
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
        var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
      }
    });
  });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id for the button is wrong.

```
<button id="checkout-button-plan_G2Z8GjQU8ZihZw" role="link" type="button">Checkout</button>
```